# Laravel 5.5 BelongsToMany with pivot conditions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have three models, `Clinic`, `Department` and `ClinicDepartment` and has `belongsToMany` relation called `departments` from `Clinic` to `Department` using `ClinicDepartment`'s table as pivot table, but when i using this relation, scopes from `ClinicDepartment` not aplying in query.

I decided to make Pivot model calling `ClinicDepartmentPivot`and apply those scopes to Pivot, but no luck.

Clinic model:

```
class Clinic extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, ActiveOnly, HasParent;

    public function departments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Department::class, 'clinic_departments', 'clinic_id', 'department_id')->using(ClinicDepartmentPivot::class);
    }
}
```

Department Model:

```
class Department extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, ActiveOnly;

    public function clinics()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Clinic::class, 'clinic_departments', 'department_id', 'clinic_id')->using(ClinicDepartmentPivot::class);
    }
}
```

ClinicDepartmentPivot Model:

```
class ClinicDepartmentPivot extends Pivot
{
    use ActiveOnly, SoftDeletes;
}
```

ActiveOnlyScope:

```
class ActiveOnlyScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->where($model->getTable() . '.is_active', true);
    }
}
```

So basicaly I want to apply global scopes to Pivot model, so when I trying to get Clinics of Department, it should check - is ClinicDepartment has `is_active = 1` and not deleted.

### UPD 1

My scope traits looks like this:

```
trait ActiveOnly
{
    public static function bootActiveOnly()
    {
        if (!Auth::guard('admin')->check() && strpos(request()->getRequestUri(), 'admin') === false) {
            static::addGlobalScope(new ActiveOnlyScope);
        }
    }
}
```

Can be used by any model.

Comment: according to the official docs, pivot model cannot have the softdelete trait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, with some workaround I finally found a working solution that does not look scrappy.

```
public function clinics()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Clinic::class, 'clinic_departments', 'department_id', 'clinic_id')
            ->where(function (Builder $query) {
                $query->where('clinic_departments.is_active', 1)
                    ->whereNull('clinic_departments.deleted_at');
            });
    }
```

Actual query looks like this:

```
select `clinics`.*, `clinic_departments`.`department_id` as `pivot_department_id`, `clinic_departments`.`clinic_id` as `pivot_clinic_id` from `clinics` inner join `clinic_departments` on `clinics`.`id` = `clinic_departments`.`clinic_id` where (`clinic_departments`.`is_active` = 1 and `clinic_departments`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

Thanks all for the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something here:

> To assign a global scope to a model, you should override a given
>   model's boot method and use the `addGlobalScope` method

[Laravel Docs on scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes)

Your models should look like these:

```
class Clinic extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, ActiveOnly, HasParent;

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new ActiveOnlyScope);
    }

    public function departments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Department::class, 'clinic_departments', 'clinic_id', 'department_id')->using(ClinicDepartmentPivot::class);
    }
}



class Department extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, ActiveOnly;

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new ActiveOnlyScope);
    }

    public function clinics()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Clinic::class, 'clinic_departments', 'department_id', 'clinic_id')->using(ClinicDepartmentPivot::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know about scopes, I am using Traits to assign global scopes, `ActiveOnly` - Trait that assigns global scope to model.
It is like Laravel's SoftDeletes Trait.
And problem not about how to use scopes in model, but how to use scopes on Pivot model.